# Error in exporting data into excel from matlab

Tags: excel, image, matlab, export-to-excel, mse

I am using the following code to read an image and comparing the image with 13 images inside a folder and finding errors and exporting it to Excel.

```
clear all;
clc;
workspace;              % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.

ReferenceImage = imread('F:\R\CS\0.8\0.6\6.jpg'); 
[rows columns] = size(ReferenceImage);

fpath = fullfile('F:\R\CT\0.0\0.2\','*.jpg');
img_dir = dir(fpath);
for k=1:length(img_dir)
input_image=strcat('F:\R\CT\0.0\0.2\',img_dir(k).name);
noisyImage = imread(input_image);

squaredErrorImage = (double(ReferenceImage) - double(noisyImage)) .^ 2;

mse = sum(sum(squaredErrorImage)) / (rows * columns);
xlswrite('F:\R\DataX.xls',mse,'A1:A13');
PSNR = 10 * log10( 256^2 / mse);
xlswrite('F:\R\DataX.xls',PSNR,'B1:B15');

end
```

I am expecting the Excel sheet to have One Column for MSE and One Column for PSNR where the calculated errors of each are displayed.

For example Lets Say,

```
Image Ref and Image 1, MSE =2; PSNR = 3
Image Ref and Image 2, MSE =3; PSNR = 3
Image Ref and Image 3, MSE =2; PSNR = 4
Image Ref and Image 4, MSE =5; PSNR = 8
```

I want the excel sheet to look like

```
2 3
3 3
2 4
5 8
```

But Instead the sheet I am creating is repeating the numbers. Please help.

Comment: Without the images your error cant be reproduced, but let me take a guess: only the first number is repeated?  try `xlswrite('F:\R\DataX.xls',mse','A1:A13');` (that little `'` behind `mse` so you dont have an 1x13 but an 13x1 vector

Comment: @Finn Ha ... was about to answer from random vectors (i.e. without loading images), but yes this is it.

Comment: Actually it looks like `mse` and `PSNR` would be sized 1x1x3 here (assuming these jpg files have 3 channels, i.e. RGB images). That's what `sum(sum(I))` would do to an image sized HxWx3. The loop should store the MSE etc. for each image in a vector and `xlswrite` should be called after the loop.

Comment: Thanks. If I generate them one image after the other I get values like, 69.7939
2.14E+03
2.54E+03
2.56E+03
2.53E+03
2.52E+03
2.49E+03
2.48E+03
2.52E+03
But If I use the above code with  xlswrite('F:\R\DataX.xls',mse','A1:A13'); I get a repeating number of 2492.08613481424